# Unable to prompt for search in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a search array where user enter the number of items, enter the value of all items and search for an array. However, I am unable to prompt for the search array to display after user enter the values of all the items. Here is an example of the desired output:

```
Enter the number of items: 5
Enter the value of all items (separated by space): 6 1 8 2 4
Enter the search key: 8
8 is found with index 2
```

Here is my coding:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchArray {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array;
    int items;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
    items = in.nextInt();

    array = new int[items];
    print(array);
    System.out.println();


}

public static void print(int[] array) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (array.length > 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter the value of all items (separated by space): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

    } 

}   




public static int search(int[] array, int key){   

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


  if (array.length > 0) {
      System.out.print("Enter the search key: ");
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; ++i){    
        if(array[i] == key){    
            key = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(key + "is present at location " + (i+1) + ".");    
        }    
    }    


  }   
  return -1;

 }

public static boolean isEmpty(int[] array) {

    if (array.length == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
}
```

It would be good if someone can help me on that. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to close the Scanner objects. This closes System.in, which cannot easily be reopened. I would create one scanner at the beginning as an instance variable and use that every time you need the scanner.

Comment: Hi, may I know what do you mean by that?

Comment: You create new Scanner object with "new Scanner(System.in)". If you close one of them, then you won't be able to get further input from any Scanner until you restart your program. Closing them is done with the close() method.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code, I see that you are not calling `search(int[] array)` which is why you dont see the desired output of:

> Enter the search key: ...

Furthermore, inside of your `print(int[] array)` function, you are setting `array[i] = in.nextInt();` however you are not using that array within the scope of that function, I would recommend returning that array and setting the one in the main function to it, so it would look something like `array = print(array)`. This allows you to change the value of the array in the main function, then you can call the `search(int[] array)` function using the array you just manipulated. The way we can allow the function to return an integer array would look like `public static int[] print(int[] array)`.

I also see in the `search(int[] array, int key)` function, that the second parameter is unnecessary because you ask for the key within that function, you are not expecting to know the key until that function is already called. When you are expecting input for the key, you should receive the input outside of the for loop since you are only asking for one key. And the search function also does not need to return anything, thus you can make the return type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

what am seeing is that your not calling the search method in the main method
like `search(array)`
Also you don't need the second parameter in the search function. instantiate 
     a global variable called key and scan the input search(key) before the for 
     loop in the search method. I have done below.

```
public class SearchArray {
    private static int[] array;
    private static int items;
    private static int key;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
        items = scanner.nextInt();


        array = new int[items];
        print(array);
        search(array);
        System.out.println();



    }

public static void print(int[] array) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(array.length > 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the value of all items (seperated by space):");
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

public static int search(int[] array) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(array.length > 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the search key: ");
            key = scanner.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == key) {
                    System.out.println(key + " is present at location " + (i+1));

                }
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }

public static boolean isEmpty(int[] array) {
        if(array.length == 0) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

output is

```
Enter the number of items: 5
Enter the value of all items (seperated by space):5 7 3 4 6
Enter the search key: 3
3 is present at location 3
```

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting but its my first time to answer a question here. I promise to improve.